# What liquid was being carried in the tanker?

Tags: mad-max-fury-road

In Mad Max: Fury Road, there are at least two liquids that were being carried, but it wasn't entirely clear what each tank contained.

I believe the rear pod contained gasoline, and the front tank may have contained "mothers milk" or water. What did the front tank contain? Why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looked to me like the rear pod contained gasoline ("guzzleline"), the big tank contained fresh water, and there were buckets or containers on the side that were full of mothers' milk that Max splashed on his face.

When Max first encountered the tanker, they had a hose that just gushed fresh water for a long time.  Max drank from that.  I got the feeling that was from the enormous tank, and that was going to be used as payment to the gasoline manufacturer Furiosa was supposed to drive to.

Later, when Max had blood on his forehead, he splashed the mothers' milk from the separate small buckets / containers attached to the side of the tanker.

Several times there was mention of the "fuel pod" being towed behind the tanker.

Comment: I forgot about the water hose. Water also makes sense given the resources of the two outposts. (I thought Max climbed back, but not sure. Also, climbing back was to reattach the brakes.)

Comment: @tedder42 Climbing back WAS to reattach the brakes!  You're right.  I'll remove that from my answer. And water makes a lot of sense given the resources of the two outposts!!

Comment: you didn't say the reattach was for fuel, but it was relevant enough to the story that I figured I'd mention. Thanks for your response.

Comment: I think in the movie they said, "guzzoline".

Comment: @chaitanya89 You're right. I didn't know how to spell it, but I like the way you spelled it.

Comment: I believe Immortan Joe's initial speech sending the tanker off referred to its contents as "aqua cola", which seems to be what his settlement (or the whole society we see in the movie) calls water (just as they call fuel guzzoline). He also uses the word water, but "aqua cola" comes up a few times - online discussion seems to generally agree that it's a sort of "brand name" Joe's come up with for his water source.

Comment: During one of the chase scenes the large tanker was hit by harpoons and water is clearly seen spilling out.

Comment: If the mothers' milk was only in the buckets on the side, how they didn't spill when travelling?

Comment: @Xriuk They had lids. They weren't open buckets.

Answer (score 3):

The front tank had both water and mothers milk.  Tankers can hold more than one liquid (i.e. different grades of gasoline)

Comment: Can you tell us where you got this information from?

Comment: It's pretty standard design for a tanker? A single tanker will take multiple different types of fuel from point to point and needs to be separated (trivially - leaded/unleaded/ethanol/diesel) and practically, you don't want to have that much volume sloshing about.